# Creating variables inside a for loop in r

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that takes a data frame and a factor variable, which then creates dummies for each level of a factor. In the code below I wrote the function, then the command lines to run it on the data set mtcars. I want my with_dummies data frame to include variables "d_6", "d_4", and "d_8". If I name my variables paste0(d_f) instead of dum, it won't run.

```
dummy_maker <- function(data, factor_variable){



 factors <- unique(factor_variable)



for (f in factors) {
   data <- data %>%
     mutate(dum = case_when( factor_variable == f ~ 1,
                                         factor_variable != f ~0 ))
 }



return(data)
  }

car_example <- mtcars
with_dummies <- dummy_maker(car_example, cyl)
```

Comment: Where did you define `cyl`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:=` to dynamically set column names in your mutate. That allows you to pass `glue` style strings. Here's an example

```
dummy_maker <- function(data, factor_variable){

  factors <- unique(data %>% pull({{factor_variable}}))

  for (f in factors) {
    data <- data %>%
      mutate("dum_{f}":= case_when( {{factor_variable}} == f ~ 1,
                              {{factor_variable}} != f ~0 ))
  }

  return(data)
}
```

also notice the use of `{{}}` to allow you to pass column names as symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether you already know the fastDummies package, which does it in a really easy way:

```
library(fastDummies)

head(dummy_cols(iris, 'Species', remove_selected_columns = TRUE))

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species_setosa Species_versicolor Species_virginica
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2              1                  0                 0
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2              1                  0                 0
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2              1                  0                 0
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2              1                  0                 0
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2              1                  0                 0
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4              1                  0                 0
```